# Non Breaking Spaces added above DataTable container. Can't stop it

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

Simple question but has me stumped. I am creating DateTables using:

```
var WC = $('#WC').dataTable();
```

When this table is rendered it ALWAYS has a huge block of non breaking spaces at the top. Same number of them. The result is the inability to get any other html element to the top of the table. They occur whether I bring data in dynamically or not. If I can't figure out how to stop DataTables from displaying them I'd like to remove them via jQuery but I am not sure how to target them as the are in div card-body but not in a child. Running regex on card-body as a whole and remove nbsp will break the program.

#SW_wrapper is the outer element that DataTables creates so you can see how they stack these breaks on top of it. Blue area below indicates where the space is created.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: We would probably need a [mre] to help you.

Comment: But also: Do you see this happening in any of the [official DataTables examples](https://datatables.net/examples/index)? What you are showing us looks like it's part of the enclosing `card-body` and maybe not related to (or caused by) DataTables. Also, you can check that you have a valid combination of DataTables and Bootstrap libraries - see [here](https://datatables.net/download/index).

Comment: Sorry but a MRE should be part of the 
 question (not a link). You can create a Stack Snippet.

Comment: I found the answer through much trial and error. It was not a DataTable issue but the way that content inside a <table> was being rendered. I need to have the <table> and all of its contents pushed far left with no indents or spaces. The table was somehow interpreting my spaces in the code and outputting them above the table itself. No other tag does that seem to be happening with.  Thanks @andrewJames for helping guide me along.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).